# 404 Error only when setting AllowInsecureHttp = false with Owin + JWT on SSL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, jwt, owin

I am receiving 404 error when deploying my Owin + WebApi to aws ec2 windows instance with SSL and AllowInsecureHttp = false, When I set it to true everything works fine for both http and https. But I don't want to allow http requests.

The error only shows when calling http or https://example.com/oauth/token

I am lost on detecting the problem between AWS, Windows Server 2016, IIS 8, Owin, JWT, Web Api. How can I debug such problem